# Re-Open a Form after done Counting time over and over

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have a problem with some codes here , its something like you have a form that maximize and control the screen, when you login you have time to use the computer, right after the time stop or end the time counting the form will maximize again .

The problem is I don't know how to catch if the timer is stop or done counting

Thank you for you time !

```
private void Monitoring_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {            
        fs.Maximize(this, this, e);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Errors");
    }
}

private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            fs.Restore(this);
            T.Show();
            if (T.IsDisposed == true)
            {
                fs.Maximize(this, this, e);
            }
            else
            { fs.Restore(this); }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Errors");
        }
}


/////////////////////////////////////



public void Maximize(Form targetForm, object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //////////////////////////////////
    ct.hidetaskbar();
    cu.DisableTaskmanager();
    cu.DisableUserSwitching();
    cu.DisableWorkstationLock();
    ck.KeyboardHook(this, e);
    ////////////////////////////////////
    targetForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    targetForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    targetForm.TopMost = true;
    targetForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    targetForm.ControlBox = false;
    FullScreen.SetWinFullScreen(targetForm.Handle);
}
////////////////////////////////////////

 public void Restore(Form targetForm)
{
    ////////////////////////////////////
    cu.EnableTaskManager();
    cu.EnableUserSwitching();
    cu.EnableWorkstationLock();
    ct.showtaskbar();
    ck.ReleaseKeyboardHook();
    ///////////////////////////////////
    targetForm.ControlBox = false;
    targetForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    targetForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    targetForm.ShowInTaskbar = true;
    targetForm.Visible = true;
    targetForm.Hide();
}

///////////////////////////////////



public partial class Timer : Form
{
    int h;
    int m = 15;
    int s;

    public Timer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Rectangle workingArea = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
        this.Location = new Point(workingArea.Right - Size.Width,
                                  workingArea.Bottom - Size.Height);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (h > 0)
        {

            if (m > 0)
            {
                if (s > 0)
                {
                    s--;
                }
                else
                {
                    s = 59;
                    m--;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                m = 59;
                h--;
            }


        }
        else
            if (h == 0)
        {
            if (m > 0)
            {
                if (s > 0)
                {
                    s--;
                }
                else
                {
                    s = 59;
                    m--;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                s--;
            }
            this.lb_h.Text = h.ToString();
            this.lb_m.Text = m.ToString();
            this.lb_s.Text = s.ToString();
        }
        if (h == 0 && m == 0 && s == 0)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void btn_end_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a reason why you dont use a [Sytem.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Oh i do use it, in Timer form
Timer form is another form show countdown timer for the user i want to catch the action isclosed or if its stopped then show the maximized form again but dont know how and where

Comment: Then u could use the [elapsed event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx) to figure out when the timer runs out

Comment: To solve the problem, divide the problem to smaller parts. For example, say I want to have a count-down timer and when the given time finished, show a message box. Remove the parts that are not relevant to the small question, the parts like WndProc and checking password. Your question is too busy to answer. It's better to edit the answer and just post a simple question :)

Comment: @Nitro.de Thanks, i'll look for that.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Okay. i'll remove that part

Comment: You should forget what I said. The `elapsed` event is only available at a `System.Timers.Timer` but not on a `Forms.Timer` there you've to use the `tick`-event

Comment: I posted an example for you. I supposed you have a `PasswordForm` which returns `DialogResult.OK` when the password is correct. And I show the password form at start, and when the time is over. The password form will be shown until the user enters the correct password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Timer` component and set a end time in your form and in `Tick` event check if the `DateTime.Now` is greater than or equals to the end time, then the given time is over.

In the below example, I supposed you have a `PasswordForm` which returns `DialogResult.OK` when the password is correct. And I show the password form at start, and when the time is over:

```
DateTime endTime;

private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowPasswordForm();
}

private void ShowPasswordForm()
{
    timer1.Stop();
    var f = new PasswordForm();
    var passed = false;
    while (!passed)
    {
        if (f.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            passed = true;
    }
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    endTime = startTime.AddMinutes(1); //I used 1 minute for test, add the time you need.
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var diff = endTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
    this.Text = string.Format("Remaining: {0} d {1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}",
                            diff.Days, diff.Hours, diff.Minutes, diff.Seconds);

    if (DateTime.Now >= endTime)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        this.Text = "Remaining: 0 d 00:00:00";
        MessageBox.Show("Time is over.");
        ShowPasswordForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why call it evry 1 second and check if overflow time limit? I think better is set timer to 15 minutes and stop right after event is called.

Comment: @Klaudiuszbryjamus It's just an example. You are right, the OP can use a better interval based on his requirement. I added a text to show the count-down of remaining time to make more sense :)

Comment: You are welcome :)  To test, it's enough to have 2 buttons in your password form that one of them sets DialogResult.OK and the other one sets DialogResult.Cancel. Then you can simply test the code. Let me know if you have any question about the answer.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Can i have another way to contact you?

Comment: While I have an email address r.aghaei at outlook.com the best way to contact me about a question is using StackOverflow. I don't use the email to answer the questions :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need it in Form you can use control from toolbar like this:

```
class Timer : Form {
    var myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    private void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs) {
        // If you want handle interval once call Stop method, if not remove this line
        myTimer.Stop();

        // Call waht you want
    }

    public void Run() {
        myTimer.Tick += TimerEventProcessor;

        // Sets the timer interval to 5 seconds.
        myTimer.Interval = 5000;
        myTimer.Start();
    }
}
```